# Unable to fix CORS policy on Google Cloud storage

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload files to Google cloud storage's bucket from a React app. I have enabled CORS setting for the bucket but it seems that I cannot still get access from the web app. I am getting the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/my_unique_bucket/ABCdio%20Vi?GoogleAccessId=storage-ucardia%40ucardia-297520.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1612456695&Signature=oxb2LVj22hc4%2FsnskKIwaq%2BK9qq88yAmnAGN1pbRJ%2BPJ2d68%2BHRRBYS24xPNwBLSkVktsjSWTBBoWv5tTkCuUAzG3Q2Q51gLdoaLUmFyGt8a4hgKJ94DeTaAJL0Hf0rwz0sNx6SkSdqrrQF%2BGlRH4HYI10JBQHuw3%2BQMPIW%2FRXTlfcvjdCkdRT9vX6twjBrC4bdIijvB31SvxbipQHWuhh6QjlKtybp3OW8kV2tY00KNWv0pE98%2FCRDBikzVkyZwM8WOYEXWUuxY9lem9LYjkBo%2BafQECApvkTQVjg%2FWJo%2BUCTVpnO5wKL58BN2QCqkmG%2FIPAwg0ptQJVMcxFhfCZw%3D%3D' from origin 'https://dashboard-fe.uc.r.appspot.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The CORS setting in JSON file is following:

```
[]
```

However, I has tried with the setting specifying the web URL and PUT method in the JSON as well, but didn't work.

**UPDATE 1:**

**Node.js API:**

```
const storage = new Storage({
    keyFilename: path.join(__dirname, '../../../projectId.json'),
    projectId: 'projectId',
});

storage.getBuckets().then((x) => {
    console.log(x);
});

const generateSignedUrl = async (req, res) => {
    const { filename, filetype } = req.query;
    // These options will allow temporary read access to the file
    const options = {
        version: 'v2', // defaults to 'v2' if missing.
        action: 'write',
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60, // one hour
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    };

    try {
        // Get a v2 signed URL for the file
        const [url] = await storage.bucket('my_unique_bucket').file(filename).getSignedUrl(options);

        res.status(ok).json({ data: url, message: GENERATE_SIGNED_URL_SUCCESS, status: true });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(internalServerError).json({ error, status: false, message: GENERATE_SIGNED_URL_FAILED });
    }
};
```

**Reactjs Client:**

```
export const putFile = async ({ url, file }) => {
    const method = 'PUT';

    return await fetch(`${url}`, {
        body: file,
        method,
        headers: {
            // Accept: file.type,
            'Content-Type': file.type,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
    });
};
```

UPDATE 2:
[This link](https://kevinsimper.medium.com/google-cloud-storage-cors-not-working-after-enabling-14693412e404) says that it is an issue with the formation of the URL but I am getting the URL as presigned URL from the google cloud storage NPM package. BTW I have followed [this link](https://jbrojbrojbro.medium.com/google-cloud-storage-and-cors-2-2-91f56af88351) to set up the mechanism but it seems I am missing something very obvious.

Comment: Hey there!. Welcome to SO. It is important to keep in mind that if you have some code issues you share with the community the code you are using in order to take a look at it.  You can take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how to improvde your question.

Comment: @SamuelRomero I have updated and added the code. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in my response. I noticed something curious in your code. You have this configuration in your JSON file

```
[]
```

However, in your react client you have this

```
headers: {
            // Accept: file.type,
            'Content-Type': file.type,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        }
```

If you have [] in your JSON file, [you are removing CORS from a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#remove-cors-bucket). Nevertheless, you are still sending the value. You need to add this to your JSON file to set the CORS in your bucket.

[
{
"origin": ["*"],
"method": ["PUT"]
}
]

[Here](https://selom.medium.com/how-to-fix-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-error-message-on-google-cloud-storage-90dd9b7e3ddb) you can find an article about it.

Comment: I have tried this but got the same error. I suspect this was some other issue and not the CORS issue however the browser is assuming it as a CORS issue. However,  I have used another way to achieve this. Thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: This is one of the most annoying problems that developers run into. Why on earth is this so hard to resolve? I've seen this on AWS S3 as well as Google Cloud. Make a giant red button that can turn CORS on and OFF. Have big warnings before deployments are made to prevent issues but just make it easy to solve. Such a waste of time for a problem that has been solved a million times.

Comment: @FawadKhalil I also have the same issue randomly now, can you please enlighten me on the other way? ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already tried setting the CORS policy for your bucket and still don't have a way around it, here's something that helped in my case:

As per this [article](https://kevinsimper.medium.com/google-cloud-storage-cors-not-working-after-enabling-14693412e404) the public URL provided from by Google does not inherently set the CORS headers. Including your bucket name in the domain for the URL should fix it.

> storage.googleapis.com/your-bucket ⬅ will not have headers
>
> your-bucket.storage.googleapis.com ⬅ will have cors headers

For example:

**Current URL:** storage.googleapis.com/your-bucket-name/file-name.mov

**New URL:** your-bucket-name.storage.googleapis.com/file-name.mov